# MongoDB - Convert array of objects to object contains array and extra fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the Mongo documents with the following structure:

```
{
   "id" : 123,
   "source" : "abc",
   "media" : [ 
        {
            "index_num" : 0,
            "media_url" : "some url"
        }, 
        {
            "index_num" : 1,
            "media_url" : "some url"
        }, 
        {
            "index_num" : 2,
            "media_url" : "some url"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `media` field is an array. How can I convert the `media` array type field into the `object` type by adding a new field called `num_images` along with the existing array like below

```
{
    "id" : 123,
    "source" : "abc",
    "media" : { 
        "media_info" : [ 
         {
             "index_num" : 0,
             "media_url" : "some url"
         }, 
         {
             "index_num" : 1,
             "media_url" : "some url"
         }, 
         {
             "index_num" : 2,
             "media_url" : "some url"
         }
       ],
       "num_images" : 3
     }
 }
```

The value for `num_images` should be the size of the `media_info` array.

I tried multiple ways by using `$arrayToObject`, `$addFields` but none of them worked properly due to syntax errors and some other errors.

Could someone please help? I am new to Mongo and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Create `new_media` field with an object contains `media_info` array and `num_images` field.
2. `$set` - Replace `media` value with `new_media`.
3. `$unset` - Remove `new_media` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "new_media": {
        "media_info": "$media",
        "num_images": {
          $size: "$media"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      media: "$new_media"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "new_media"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bPn5FMpvu4t)

Comment: Hi, @Yong Shun I just realised the aggregate pipeline only shows the data but does not commit it (or alter existing data).. How do I commit this modified document to the collection

Comment: You can update with aggregation pipeline. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SwqwFeW-8-5)